# Access assets from subprojects with Play framework 2.1.1

Tags: playframework-2.0

i'm currently working on a Play ! 2.1.1 application defining multiple subprojects. Here is my Build.scala :

```
val lfamName = "lfam"
val lfamVersion = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
val lfamDirectory = "subprojects/" + lfamName
lazy val lfam = play.Project(lfamName, lfamVersion, appDependencies, path = file(lfamDirectory))

val mainName = "main"
val mainVersion = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
lazy val main = play.Project(mainName, mainVersion, appDependencies)
            .settings().dependsOn(lfam).aggregate(lfam)
```

The resulting struture :

```
app
  └ controllers
    └> Application.scala
  └ models
  └ views
    └> index.scala.html
  └ assets
    └ stylesheets
      └> main.less
conf
  └> application.conf
  └> routes
subprojects
  └ lfam
    └ conf
      └> lfam.routes
    └ app/controllers
      └> Application.scala
      └> Assets.scala
    └ app/models
    └ app/views
      └> index.scala.html
    └ assets
      └ stylesheets
        └> main.less
```

The sources :

routes

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index

-> /lfam lfam.Routes

GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

lfam.routes

```
GET     /                           controllers.lfam.Application.index

GET     /assets/*file               controllers.lfam.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Assets.scala

```
package controllers.lfam
object Assets extends controllers.AssetsBuilder
```

Application.scala (just the package name changes between project)

```
package controllers(.lfam)

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index())
  }

}
```

main.less (main project)

```
@main-color: #0000ff;

h1 {
  color: @main-color;
}
```

main.less (lfam project)

```
@main-color: #ff0000;

h1 {
  color: @main-color;
}
```

index.scala.html (main project)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.scala.html (lfam project)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@lfam.routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

When the subproject index is displayed (/lfam/) the header is still blue. But if i rename the main.less file from subproject to lfam.less (and the corresponding  in html) the header becomes red(as expected).

Is it possible to have multiple assets in multiple subprojects, with the same name ? How is play not serving me the right css file in the first case but finding the second one ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible since [all projects in a multi-project setup use the same classloader](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1181).

Assets are loaded using `ClassLoader.getResource` [(source)](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Application.scala#L373). Just like Java source code, the fully qualified resource name must be unique.